# i can't change the colors on the lines in a multi line graph with d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

it seems like i am doing everything right except the fact that i can't change the colors to distinguish between the lines, this code should work:

```
colors = ["blue","red","yellow","green","black","blue","gray"];
linesGroup = svg.append("g").attr("class", "lines");
var linedata;
for (var i in chart_data) {
    linedata = chart_data[i];
        console.log(linedata);
    linesGroup.append("path")
    .attr("d", line(linedata.points))
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("fill", "none")
   .attr("stroke", function(d, i) { 
       console.log(colors[Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1)]);
       return colors[colors[Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1)]];
    });;

};
```

i am also using jsfiddle for the full example
http://jsfiddle.net/yr2Nw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the stroke as an inline style instead and access the color array properly:

```
   .style("stroke", function(d, i) { 
       return colors[Math.floor((Math.random()*6)+1)];
    });
```

Using a `for in` loop isn't a super [idiomatic](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) way of getting things done in d3 (you'll run into problems if you try to use `i`).

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for your help, it worked like a charm. It is the only way i ve found to draw multiple lines.